# Anime.js svg morph animation on hover not reversing when animation is not complete

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, anime.js

I have this code that animates paths from a svg when I hover over it. It works great when I let the animation complete but when it's not complete yet the second part does not play.

I'm guessing I can do something with the anime.js reverse and play functions or something with a timeline but I'm stuck.

```js
$('#logo').hover(function() {
    anime({
    targets: [this.querySelector('#back')],
    d: [
      { value: 'm 4 100 h -4 v -100 h 0 z' },
      { value: 'm 38 100 h -38 v -100 h 0 z' },
      { value: 'm 38 100 h -38 v -100 h 50 z' },
      { value: 'm 87 100 h -87 v -100 h 50 z' },
      { value: 'm 87 100 h -87 v -100 h 128 z' },
      { value: 'M 175 100 h -175 v -100 h 125 Z' },
      { value: 'M 175 100 h -175 v -100 h 175 Z' },
    ],
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    duration: 500 
    });
}, function() {
    anime({
    targets: [this.querySelector('#back')],
    d: [
    { value: 'M 175 100 h -175 v -100 h 175 Z' },
    { value: 'M 175 100 h -175 v -100 h 125 Z' },
    { value: 'm 87 100 h -87 v -100 h 128 z' },
    { value: 'm 87 100 h -87 v -100 h 50 z' },
    { value: 'm 38 100 h -38 v -100 h 50 z' },
    { value: 'm 38 100 h -38 v -100 h 0 z' },
    { value: 'm 4 100 h -4 v -100 h 0 z' },
  ],
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart',
    duration: 150 
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #1d1e22
}

div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 175px;
  margin-top: 10%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>

<div><svg id="logo" data-name="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="175" height="100" viewBox="0 0 175 100">
<path id="back" d="m 4 100 h 0 v -100 h 0 z" fill="#ed1e79"/>
  <g id="frame">
    <polygon points="69.894 85.938 72.914 85.938 71.418 81.97 69.894 85.938" fill="#fff"/>
    <path d="M48.3137,81.535H46.8723v6.7521h1.4414c1.7847,0,3.7891-.73,3.7891-3.3624C52.1028,82.1278,50.0984,81.535,48.3137,81.535Z" fill="#fff"/>
    <path d="M92.0224,81.535H90.5809v6.7521h1.4415c1.7844,0,3.7887-.73,3.7887-3.3624C95.8111,82.1278,93.8068,81.535,92.0224,81.535Z" fill="#fff"/>
    <path d="M.0676.1441v100h175v-100ZM26.391,89.8027H24.6752V81.9622h-.0275l-2.9515,7.8405H20.4879l-2.91-7.8405H17.55v7.8405H15.9028V80.0472h2.7044l2.5261,6.9308h.0411l2.4986-6.9308h2.718Zm12.9452,0H32.6506V80.0472H39.089v1.5157H34.38v2.48h4.4616v1.46H34.38v2.756h4.9559Zm9.2522,0H45.1425V80.0472h3.4459c2.54,0,5.3677,1.2124,5.3677,4.8775C53.9561,88.3423,51.1281,89.8027,48.5884,89.8027Zm12.89,0h-1.73V80.0472h1.73Zm13.0138,0L73.5862,87.57H69.3715l-.8786,2.2325H66.5574l4.2281-9.7555h1.4964l4.187,9.7555Zm17.8047,0H88.8512V80.0472h3.4455c2.54,0,5.368,1.2124,5.368,4.8775C97.6647,88.3423,94.8367,89.8027,92.2967,89.8027Zm17.8457,0h-6.6853V80.0472h6.4382v1.5157h-4.7087v2.48h4.4616v1.46h-4.4616v2.756h4.9558Zm8.4153.2481a4.4231,4.4231,0,0,1-3.3364-1.3916l1.2357-1.1579a2.7642,2.7642,0,0,0,2.1279,1.0748c.81,0,1.7572-.3994,1.7572-1.4468,0-1.0195-1.0157-1.3085-2.2379-1.6949-1.18-.3721-2.4572-.9507-2.4572-2.7695,0-1.9839,1.7986-2.8657,3.5558-2.8657a4.2327,4.2327,0,0,1,2.8279,1.0474l-1.1257,1.24a2.3781,2.3781,0,0,0-1.7844-.84c-.7964,0-1.7164.3857-1.7164,1.3364,0,.8955.755,1.1572,1.8536,1.502,1.2493.3857,2.8415.937,2.8415,2.852C122.0993,89.0306,120.4657,90.0508,118.5577,90.0508Zm11.1191-.2481h-1.73V80.0472h1.73Zm14.7707-.51a8.2427,8.2427,0,0,1-3.6658.7579,5.1285,5.1285,0,1,1-.0408-10.2516,5.5509,5.5509,0,0,1,3.6923,1.226l-1.1943,1.2955a3.4448,3.4448,0,0,0-2.4844-.9922,3.5867,3.5867,0,0,0,.0822,7.1651,5.001,5.001,0,0,0,1.9358-.3448v-2.48h-2.0458V84.2357h3.7208Zm14.7849.51h-2.1966l-4.6129-7.5372h-.0272v7.5372h-1.73V80.0472h2.2928l4.5166,7.3028h.0272V80.0472h1.73ZM171.5,70.7715H3.6357V3.7254H171.5Z" fill="#fff"/>
  </g>
  <path id="lettern" d="M47.9876,18.2283V57.0422h-7.95L20.56,20.1657V55.9594h3.1232v1.0828h-7.78V55.9594h3.1231V18.2283H15.9028V17.1448H31.5761L46.4538,45.7574V18.2283H43.3307V17.1448h7.78v1.0835Z" fill="#fff"/>
  <path id="letterv" d="M90.577,46.7258l9.8813-28.4975H96.0289V17.1448h8.6884v1.0835h-2.6689L88.3623,57.6126h-4.77l-14.48-39.3843H66.5V17.1448H85.0687v1.0835H81.0371Z" fill="#fff"/>
  <path id="letterd" d="M159.2323,36.41q0,11.742-6.5871,16.3575-6.0771,4.2747-16.6958,4.2747H119.8788V55.9594h3.7484V18.2283h-3.7484V17.1448h17.5473q10.903,0,16.3543,4.4744T159.2323,36.41ZM134.7,55.9594h2.1584q5.735,0,8.2057-4.0751t2.47-13.6507V34.9279q0-12.8243-4.8837-15.4457a14.1046,14.1046,0,0,0-6.5871-1.2539H134.7Z" fill="#fff"/>
  </svg></div>
```

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/Biellos/pen/mdOZoWb

Comment: For sure, edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding

```
anime.remove('#back');
```

Before each animation.